# use different types, or use Object?

Tags: java, object

Sorry for noobish question, but why we even use `String`, `int` and others, if we can just use Object as a type?

I mean use `Object one;` instead of `String one;`

Comment: What can you *do* with `one` after you've declared it as type `Object`? Compare that with what you can do with it when you've declared it as type `String`...

Comment: i hope u have learned about Object oriented programming before asking this question.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan sorry, i am reading lots of tutorials about everything, and some things just arent so obvious to a noob like me.

Comment: For the same reason that we use programming languages instead of writing hexadecimal values directly to memory.  We've adapted to more human-readable abstractions over the underlying system to allow for easier creation and support of more complex applications.  As an exercise, write a complete application using *only* `Object` as a type.  See how the code looks.

Comment: @lxknvlk yes because tutorials are not book!! one should access net if there is trouble in understanding from book...

Comment: You might want to look at this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270862/difference-between-object-creation-syntax, and especially my answer (plug, plug, plug :).

Comment: @lxknvlk Your other fall back when you don't know the answer is to write yourself a short code snippet and try it out. You will find out, when trying to call String methods on an Object reference, that you can't.

Answer (score 2):

For example, the `String` class declares a bunch of methods. If your variable is declared as `Object`, then only the methods declared in `Object` and its super classes (none) are visible on that variable, regardless of the type of the actual object.

You can do

```
String one = new String("whatever");
System.out.println(one.length());
```

but you can't do

```
Object one = new String("whatever");
System.out.println(one.length());
```

Methods and fields are resolved on the compile time type of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because in some cases if you know, you will have a `String`, it's better to use:

```
String str = "foo";
int length = str.length();
```

instead of doing it with typecasting like this:

```
Object str = "foo";
try {
    int length = ((String)str).length();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    // and now what?
}
```

by not knowing if `str` is really a `String`!

The class `Object` is only providing the `Object`s methods. So you can't access for example this `length()` method on an `Object`.

So, everytime you know, that you will only able to handle a `String`, **use** a `String`!

If you are not sure what you will have, you have to use `Object` and do your special logic around (typecasting, error handling on a `ClassCastException` and so on...).

Answer (score 0):

Because `Object` is the lowest common denominator. It's also not type safe and you would have to cast to the specific type each time you wanted to do something specific to that class.

Answer (score 0):

**Quite a few reasons really..**

- Try and use `charAt` on a `String` object, referred to by an `Object` type reference. If we only used `Object` type references, we would only be able to use `Object` methods, which aren't exactly useful.
- Some methods *require* `String` types, and not `Object` types. For example, `string.substring()` takes one or two `arguments` of type `int`. This will not compile if you pass an `Object` in, unless you cast it. Which means, every time you want to use some native Java functionality that doesn't accept type `Object`, and requires a more specific reference type, you've got to cast it... which is most of the time.
- So the code makes some bloody sense. Using these types means that you automatically know the kind of data that it will hold, just by looking at the variable type. `String` will hold some text. `int` holds an integer, `double` holds a large decimal. This all helps in making code more readable, and thus more extendable.